# xml layout not showing background color

Tags: android

[image]**Xml layout is showing dark background in graphical layout but not showing it in emulator.Everything was working fine before adding listview to the layout file .**

*
this is my layout output after executing

[image]
this is my graphical layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relRingtone"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#000000"
>  
            <ListView
               android:focusable="false"
             android:id="@+id/list_notification"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
             android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
             android:layout_marginLeft="3dip" 
             android:textSize="2dp" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="40dp" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Start Working"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Chronometer
                android:id="@+id/chronometer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/btn1"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Vehicle  Details"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/btn2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/chronometer"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Take Leave"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>


     </RelativeLayout>
```

Xml layout is showing dark background in graphical layout but not showing it in emulator.Everything was working fine before adding listview to the layout file .

Comment: May be your list view is filled with list items while running. If that is the case make the List item layout background colour `@android:color/transparent`

Comment: You are using RelativeLayout in the inner part which is causing the problem. The listview is below the inner RelativeLayout and this is why the color of the background of the view seems not to be black as in the background is the listview. Either you make your parent layout LinearLayout or just make your inner RelativeLayout to fall below the ListView.

Comment: May be this will help you..Add this line in your listview 
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"

Comment: i tried adding background in listview and that too was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving cachecolorhint attribute of the listview and make it transparent like below mentioned snippet:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relRingtone"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#000000"
>  
            <ListView
               android:focusable="false"
             android:id="@+id/list_notification"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
             android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
             android:layout_marginLeft="3dip" 
             android:textSize="2dp" 
           android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"/>
             />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="40dp" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"

                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Start Working"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Chronometer
                android:id="@+id/chronometer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/btn1"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Vehicle  Details"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/btn2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/chronometer"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"

                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Take Leave"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>


     </RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: i am getting this kind of output (see the edited answer)if i run code.........is this what you want or something else???

Comment: ok thanks ..... I saw your output in emulator....Also can you please tell me which theme are you using???? You can check that in your manifest file....it will be in the application tag....

Comment: like this........ <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

Comment: you did what i exactly want,can you please add listview above two button and add your code to the answer.

Comment: i have used the same theme you have pasted.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35399/discussion-between-nidhi-and-user2523388)

Answer (score 2):

Try to give color to the `ListView` or make it transparent.

Answer (score -3):

can you please explain how excatly u want to design ur layout ... as its little bit confusing 
 But still I've tried to solved from whatever the things i understand from ur question.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relRingtone"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000000" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_notification"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/reltivebutton"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/reltivebutton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:paddingBottom="40dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Start Working"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Chronometer
            android:id="@+id/chronometer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Vehicle  Details"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/chronometer"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Take Leave"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: plz fix ur spelling to be real English. Text-speak is not as clear as real English.

Comment: This isn't a text message with your friends. Please use proper English spelling and grammar as this is a global site that is visited by people from all over the world. Even for me, a native English speaker, your answer was difficult to read at first. Imagine how it would be for someone that isn't fluent in the language.

Comment: @KimberlyW Thanks for the notifying. Made changes in Answer.

Comment: The answer is still in text message language and not English. "u" is not a word and neither is "ur".